# How do I extract operation count from Clustertime in Mongdob?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My objective is to extract the operation count from MongoDB clustertime.

I.e. in other words, how do I get this "i" value in a pipeline?

[image]

Currently we "extract" the time like this:

```
$addFields: {
  clusterTimeAsDate: {
      $toDate: { $dateToString: { date: '$clusterTime' } },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question is about aggregation, there will be `$tsIncrement` operator added in v5.1 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-56874.

Must be something like this:

```
$addFields: {
  clusterTimeAsDate: {
      $toDate: { $dateToString: { date: '$clusterTime' } },
  },
  clusterTimeIncrement: { $tsIncrement: '$clusterTime' }
}
```

The docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/tsIncrement/#mongodb-expression-exp.-tsIncrement

**update**

It might be more efficient to use `$tsSecond` to convert to Date when you upgrade.